# R, sapply does not seem to apply the function provided

Tags: r

Looking into the apply function family, sapply does not produce what I would like to. The problem I simplified to a basic example below. I create a vector and then perform a sum operation.

```
1.
v<-c(1:9)
sum(v)
#this returns 45 as expected

2.
sapply (v, sum)
#this returns [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

How should I use sapply() to sum the vector above? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You wouldn't, really. If you want the sum of the elements of a vector, `sapply` isn't the tool you want. You just want `sum(v)`.

Comment: What is the desired output? Are you looking for `cumsum`?

Comment: `sapply(v, sum)` means do `sum` on each element of `v`. So you get a result that is the sum of [1], sum of [2], etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sapply` applies a function to each element of a list. So what you're doing here is applying `sum` to each number on its own – which doesn't accomplish anything. You can see what's happening in this example:

```
sapply(1:9, function(x) x + 1)
[1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Using `sum` with `apply` only makes sense if you want to sum multiple elements of a list:

```
sapply(list(1:9, 3:4), sum)
[1] 45  7
```

Here, `sum` is applied  to each vector in the list

Answer (score 2):

If you must use `sapply`, try,

```
sapply (list(v), sum)
[1] 45
```

The function `sapply` applies the function `sum` to each element. So for the vector `v`, it was summing up each individual element.

It is clear the sum of one element, is that element.

Using the `list` function, we them apply the `sum` function to the first element of the list, which is `v`, giving the desired result.

Just for understanding, we can use any function to move the vector "down a level", like `data.frame`,

```
> sapply(data.frame(v), sum)[[1]]
[1] 45
```

But in your case, there is no need for `sapply`.

Answer (score 0):

you would use the reduce functional in this case

```
    v<-c(1:9)
    sum(v)
    #this returns 45 as expected

    purrr::reduce(v,sum)
    #this also returns 45

    # or base R
    Reduce(sum,v)
    # this also returns 45
```

Comment: What `reduce` is that? Base R's `Reduce` is capital.

Comment: Add `library(purrr)` to your answer. This is where `reduce` is from.